# Can I configure Bitcoin (Linux) with a custom wallet location?

Tags: bitcoin-core

The default setup on Linux/Ubuntu has Bitcoin storing the data in the `~/.bitcoin` folder, which is usually not encrypted with [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt).

Suppose I do now want to rely on the internal Bitcoin encryption system, but instead want to save the wallet to disk on using TrueCrypt encryption. Currently, I have a separate TrueCrypt data file, that I mount to a partition, copy files from it to `~/.bitcoin`, and when I'm finished, I copy the files back to the truecrypt volume, and shred+delete the copies on `~/.bitcoin`.

This is bothersome and error prone.

Can I configure Bitcoin to only take the wallet from `/media/trucrypt`, but keep the blockchain data in `~/.bitcoin`?

Comment: I haven't tried, but maybe you could copy once to `/media/trucrypt` and then bind mount to `~/.bitcoin` with `mount -B /media/trucrypt ~/.bitcoin`?

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bitcoin startup argument `-datadir=<dir>` allows you to specify a data directory, including the wallet file.

That'll still require you to pass a custom argument I'm afraid. The config file is also in the data dir, hence there's a chicken-and-the-egg problem that makes it impossible to configure up ahead. **Unless** you're savvy enough to change the default constant in the source and recompile, which might be okay since you're already running Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Symlink the wallet.dat file into the truecrypt volume

Answer (score 1):

A solution has been discussed, but not implemented:
 - http://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/68  https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/287

Comment: Hmm, it appears I'm actually already following that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you, it seems quite easy to do:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_your_wallet#Making_a_new_wallet