# Data directory issue

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have everything set up normally. My only issue is that my data directory is in `C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin`.

Normaly this is what you would want, but, if you noticed, my username has a space in it (obviously I changed it for privacy) so when I try to designate my data directory in the miner program it says the directory does not exist because the space in my username causes the directory link to break ( `C:\Users\User` ) instead of the full link...

Is there a way I can change where [Bitcoin-Qt](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin-Qt) stores its data by default?

And no, a re-directory won't work, because it can't find the location in the first place.

Comment: I was having disk space problem, so I installed it in E:\
I created a separate directory for storing data first.
Then, I created a shortcut to bitcoin=qt.exe on my desktop and added the parameter in the target as described above. Now it's working fine, thanks.

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259/bitcoin-qt-setup-change-block-chain-file-location-settings-documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run bitcoin with the parameter `-datadir=C:\New\Dir`

E.g. create a shortcut and change "target" to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -datadir=C:\BitcoinData`

Comment: where do i go to add the parameter?

Comment: ok i created a shortcut for bitcoin-qt and i added -datadir=C:\BitcoinData to the end but it just says C:\BitcoinData doesnt exist

Comment: issue solved, i changed my Username via another admin account and regedit to change the log in defaults

Comment: `-datadirC:\BitcoinData` as strange as it is, do not put no nothing between datadir and your dir.....