# Can I change the bitcoin block-data directory from /home/user/.bitcoin/blocks to something else?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, full-node

I have two users on my Linux system, *daemonuser*, which runs bitcoind and *abeuser*, which runs Abe.

Whenever I start Abe, I am told:

> Skipping datadir /home/daemonuser/.bitcoin/blocks: [Errno 13]
>   Permission denied: '/home/daemonuser/.bitcoin/blocks/blk0001.dat'

Even after adding *abeuser* as a readable user on the /home/daemonuser/.bitcoin/blocks/ directory.

Would it be easier to keep bitcoin's blockdata in a public folder and read it from there for Abe's purposes?

Comment: That's for windows :S And bitcoinqt. Does the same work on bitcoind on linux? If so, awesome!

Comment: Bitcoind is exactly the same codebase as Bitcoin-Qt, only compiled without GUI. There's very little difference between the versions for different OS'es too. One notable exception is the location of the standard datadir.

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make the files in the `.bitcoin/blocks/` directory readable for Abe? You can test this by logging in as Abe (`sudo su abeuser` should suffice) and typing `strings ~daemonuser/.bitcoin/blocks/any.file`.