# Using the main Bitcoin-Qt Client, can you change where it stores the block chain?

Tags: client, bitcoin-core

I don't want 12 gigabytes stored on my boot drive.  Can I change where the  Bitcoin-Qt stores the block chain?

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely can. Just add **-datadir** parameter to the command line, when starting bitcoin-qt.
For example:

> bitcoin-qt.exe -datadir=D:\BITCOINDATA