# where is default Bitcoin-Qt data directory?

Tags: client, portable

I want to make portable client so I found with `start bitcoin-qt.exe -datadir=data`

But where is default data dir so I can move it there?

Comment: A closer-matching duplicate is (this question is about ***changing*** it, not just about where it is): *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your operating system.  Read about it [**here**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory).

**Linux**

```
~/.bitcoin/
```

**Mac**

```
~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/
```

**Windows**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin (XP)

C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin (Vista and 7)
```

Comment: Hi ScripterRon! You can improve this answer by including the relevant information in the answer instead of just providing a link. Thanks!

Comment: @D.H. I just added this info to the answer.